# How do I access SSID info from postup() in Gentoo's OpenRC /etc/conf.d/net

Tags: wireless-networking, gentoo, openvpn

I would like to fire up openvpn (or stop it) depending on what wireless network I'm connected to.

But dumping `env` from [postup()](http://git.overlays.gentoo.org/gitweb/?p=proj/openrc.git;a=blob;f=doc/net.example.Linux.in#l1188) does not indicate `${SSID}` being available at that time.

Staring at [net/wpa_supplicant.sh](http://git.overlays.gentoo.org/gitweb/?p=proj/openrc.git;a=blob;f=net/wpa_supplicant.sh#l71) doesn't seem to help, so I'm turning to hivemind for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was originally looking to not launch openvpn based on the SSID I was connecting to. But the better solution I arrived at is to [look at the IP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8631877/35946).

**/etc/conf.d/net**:

```
postup() {
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845694/how-do-i-find-my-computers-ip-address-using-the-bash-shell
    IP=$(ifconfig ${IFACE} | sed -n 's/.*inet addr:\([0-9.]\+\)\s.*/\1/p')
    OPENVPN=$(if [[ "${IFACE}" != "tun0" && ${IP%.*} != 192.168.[13] ]]; then echo "YES"; fi)

    sw-notify-send -i "${ICONS}/network-status.png" "${IFACE}" "$(ip addr show dev ${IFACE} | grep inet)"

    if [[ -n ${OPENVPN} ]]; then
        sw-notify-send -i "${ICONS}/network-status.png" "${IFACE}" "No IP range conflict detected for ${IP}, starting openvpn"
        /etc/init.d/openvpn -D restart
    fi
    return 0
}
```

**EDIT** Even further, I've now moved this logic on to a [dhcpcd](http://roy.marples.name/projects/dhcpcd/) hook. For this to work, you should send some unique dhcp option value from your special DHCP server: I'm using option 114 "default_url" here.

**/etc/dhcpcd.enter-hook**:

```
ACTION="stop"
COMMAND="openvpn.noroutes"    

if [ "$reason" = "BOUND" ]; then
    if [ ! -z ${new_default_url} ]; then
        sw-notify-send $ifname "Detected DHCP default_url $new_default_url, skipping openvpn"
        exit 1
    fi

    OPENVPN=$(if [[ $ifname != "tun0" && ${new_network_number%.*} != 192.168.[13] ]]; then echo "YES"; fi)
    if [[ -n $OPENVPN ]]; then
        sw-notify-send $ifname "IP range for $new_ip_address is free, starting openvpn"
        COMMAND="openvpn"
    fi

    ACTION="restart"

    /etc/init.d/"${COMMAND}" -D "${ACTION}"
fi
```

Comment: I've now moved my VPN start/stop logic into /etc/dhcpcd.enter-hook.